# Adding an Armature to an already existing model

Tags: modeling, armature, bones

I have downloaded a .stl file, but I want to change the pose. It has no bones or Armature I think. Trying to add them, but I don't know where to start or if I even can. Does it need to be another file type? Can I even add an armature and bones to a pre-existing model I imported? I just want to change the pose of a model I found.

Comment: Once anything is (succesfully) imported into Blender is part of a Blender file, even if unsaved, and acts like anything, that was created in Blender, the file type is now .blend. Armature can influence geometry as found in meshes. To answer your 2 question: (1) no (2) yes